# Is it possible to search through an array and return the index of the value

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am writing a simple Java program that basically stores an array of artists that have been in the charts previously; this is my code so far for the program

```
package searching;

import java.util.*;

public class Searching {
    public static void main(String[] args) {          
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String artists[] = {"Rihanna", "Cheryl Cole", "Alexis Jordan", "Katy Perry", "Bruno Mars",
                        "Cee Lo Green", "Mike Posner", "Nelly", "Duck Sauce", "The Saturdays"};

        System.out.println("Please enter an artist...");
        String artist = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

I was just wondering, is it possible for the user to type the name of one of the artists, get the code to search the array and return the index of that value? and if so how would I go about it as I don't know where to begin... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop through the artists array in a for loop and then return the index if the value equals the `artist` value.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {
        String artistElement = artists[i];
        if (artistElement.equals(artist)) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Here's what happened for me:

```
Please enter an artist...
Mike Posner
6
```

Comment: -1: Cool, now you solve homeworks for free in a worldwide site.

Comment: Please refer to [How to ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/182862) for future similar questions before solving homeworks for OP.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Quoting your link: "`Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith, even if they break these guidelines.`"

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza He didn't explicitly state it was homework.  Even if he did, I took time out of my day to write this myself to be helpful to someone who needed help.  I'm sorry if you didn't like the way I did it, but you don't have to act like the boss of SO.

Comment: @tieTYT not acting like a boss or something similar. By the way, by reading the question content you can understand that it is an exercise, it's no rocket science...

Comment: @tieTYT, thanks mate really appreciate the help... and as for people being arsey it was not homework, it was me trying to get back into Java after a couple years off.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Oh for pete's sake give over. Many people learn through the fantastic forum of SO. Without this amazing resource I wouldn't be able to do half the things I can now. We all learn in different ways. Staring at a screen for hours on end doesn't appeal to me. Finding out an answer quickly, reading through and understanding that answer and developing my knowledge of that particular part of the language is far more appealing to me - hence why I have no problem posting a simple answer to a simple problem.

Comment: Look... Java isn't a language I particularly enjoy; I prefer to write PHP, JQuery and languages like that, now can you please refrain from trying to instigate any more arguments on this post that are completely irrelevant, if that's how you feel then that's your choice but please, take it elsewhere.

Comment: @user2406160 This code works for Java, the algorithm works on almost every programming language. Still, it's up to you to define the best way to learn, not me.

Comment: True, let's all end the debate there and avoid extended discussion in the comments section - it's not the place for it.

Comment: I know it works... but how I learn is really none of your business anyway.

Answer (score 5):

With an unsorted array, one option would be to put the artists in a List and use [List.indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
 List<String> artistsList = Arrays.asList( artists );
 ...
 int index = artistsList.indexOf( artist );
```

If the artists were sorted, you could use [Arrays.binarySearch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 3):

> I was just wondering, is it possible for the user to type the name of one of the artists, get the code to search the array and return the index of that value?

Yes, it is possible.

Since *you don't know where to begin*, I would say you can start going through the array (probably using a `for` loop) and validating if the `artist` variable is **equals** to the current element of the array. If they're **equals**, then you can just return the current index of the element of the array. If nothing is found, then return a default value like -1 that you can handle and return a message like *Artist not found*.

Comment: I like the start, but I'd recommend writing it as a small appropriately named method (and perhaps showing what the signature might look like). Then it becomes more natural: `if (knownArtist(artist)) { .. } else { .. }`.

Comment: @user2246674 sorry, but that's doing almost 50% (or more) of the homework.

Comment: I disagree. It's merely providing guidance on dividing a problem up into logical bite-sized parts. The homework can be completed without this suggestion (as per the guidance in this answer).

Comment: @user2246674 - Breaking up a problem into bite-sized parts is one of the major tasks and skills in programming.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer I agree! Which is why new programmers should be *taught* and *guided* on how to do it. It is a *learned skill* and one can flounder all the way through a CS program and still write absolutely terrible code.

Comment: @user2246674 but that's something you learn with practice. If you don't practice it, you will never learn it...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza And, for some people, if they're never told, they'll never grasp it .. so back to my original comment (which was not meant to instill such an argument): "I'd recommend writing it as a small appropriately named method (and perhaps showing what the signature might look like)."

Comment: @user2246674 - Good idea -- but providing the code does not accomplish that.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer I do not believe I said "provide the code".

Comment: @user2246674 - "... I'd recommend writing it as a small appropriately named method ..." If it was not your intention to suggest providing Java code or pseudocode, this discussion is pointless. I'm withdrawing, regardless.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer "[I would] recommend writing it *as* a small appropriately named method .."

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like so:

```
int index = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {
    if (artist.equals(artists[i]))
        index = i;
}

if (index == -1)
    System.out.println("Artist not found");
else
    System.out.println("Index of artist: " + index);
}
```

This isn't as eloquent as tieTYT's solution, but does the trick. The index is set to -1. The for loop compares each artist to each value in your array. If a match is found, the index is set to the index of the element.

After the for loop, if the index is still -1, the user is informed that no match was found, otherwise the appropriate artist and index are output.

The user of a for loop is the most common way to scroll through the contents of an array and compare elements against a given value. By calling artists[i], every element of the array can be checked against the input String.

Comment: -1: Same as @tieTYT: Please refer to [How to ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/182862) for future similar questions before solving homeworks for OP.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: You'll be here a long time if you're going to downvote every single attempt to help a new user. I will continue to do so as so many helpful SO users helped me when I was starting out.

Comment: If I were like that, then I would have downvoted OP's question and even voted to close. Instead, I provided an answer explaining a way to solve the problem instead of *giving the full answer*, making just another zombie coder who just copy/paste whatever he/she can see in a post on the net.